# please wait git is being initialized

Tags: windows, adobe, dreamweaver, creative-cloud

I am using adobe dreamweaver cc 2018 on windows 10 PC.

When I creating new site "Associate a git repository with this site" always disabled and showing a message " please wait git is being initialized".

What is the issue?